# nginx fastcgi_read_timeout counted as fail

Tags: nginx

If timeout of fastcgi_read_timeout is triggered, then that request counted as failure? Will that be registered as fail in upstream block and mark that server as failed and remove it from healthy servers list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly.

> [fastcgi_read_timeout:](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout)
>   Defines a timeout for reading a response from the FastCGI server. The
>   timeout is set only between two successive read operations, not for
>   the transmission of the whole response. If the FastCGI server does not
>   transmit anything within this time, the connection is closed.